# how to compare two std::set?

Tags: c++, set, std

I do such comparison of two `std::set`

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

#include <vector>
#include <set>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int myints1[]= {10,20,30,40,50};
    int myints2[]= {50,40,30,20,10};
    std::set<int> s1 (myints1,myints1+5);
    std::set<int> s2(myints2,myints2+5);
    if(s1==s2){
        printf("sets: true");
    }else printf("sets: false");
    std::set<int>::iterator it2=s2.begin();
    for(std::set<int>::iterator it1=s1.begin();it1!=s1.end();it1++){
                printf("\ns1: %d  s2: %d",*it1,*it2);
        it2++;
    }
}
```

output:

```
sets: true
s1: 10  s2: 10
s1: 20  s2: 20
s1: 30  s2: 30
s1: 40  s2: 40
s1: 50  s2: 50
```

**Question:**

Is this the right way to do it? Or is any other (special) way of comparing two sets?

Comment: If `std::set` implements `operator==` I'd expect it to be correct.

Comment: It does implement it, and it does do the right thing. But is that the question? Or are you asking whether the `for`-loop is correct?

Comment: If you are looking for a way to determine the elements `s1` and `s2` do _not_ have in common, you may want to look at [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) from the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: I am not sure if `std::set` implements `==` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/). If you have some object (which does not have `==` overloaded) instead of `int`, I am not sure if you will get the same result

Comment: I use operator == in s1==s2, I am asking if this is correct if yes, please answer I will accept it, alternatively how should it be done?

Comment: Alternatively, iterate over the sets (similar to what you have), and compare each element. I think it is safer that way.

Comment: @jogojapan Of all the commenters that answered correctly, you would get the most out of a reputation bump.  :)  Consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: @DrewDormann Nice way of looking at it... anyway, too late...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, `operator==` is correctly defined for all standard containers (**except** the unordered containers - based on 23.2.5.2 of the standard), and will generally do a  lexicographic comparison. See for example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp). The relevant quote:

> Checks if the contents of lhs and rhs are equal, that is, whether lhs.size() == rhs.size() and each element in lhs has equivalent element in rhs at the same position.

Since `std::set` is an ordered container, any set with the same size and same elements (given the comparators are the same) will necessarily have them in the same position, hence will compare equal.

Comment: but two sets with identical elements but in different positions mathematically are equal. Are they equal also in std::set== ? I think yes, but iterating and comapre would lead us to misleading results

Comment: @gumtree `std::set` does not keep the elements in the order you inserted them. It sorts them. So, iterating will work just like `==` works (and `std::equal` works, too, in the same way).

Comment: @gumtree That's the point - `set` is ordered (the second template argument to it is a comparison operator), hence two sets having the same comparator and the same elements **cannot** have them in different positions.

Comment: Unordered containers also have `operator==` (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/operators/) or better, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/operator_cmp))

Answer (score 34):

There are several set operations in C++ standard library header `<algorithm>`.

[`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) gives those elements that are in set 1 but not set 2.

[`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) gives those elements that are in both sets.

[`std::set_symmetric_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) gives those elements that appear in one of the sets but not both.

[`std::set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) gives those elements that are in either set 1 or set 2.

The algorithms above can also be applied to STL containers other than `std::set`, but the containers have to be sorted first (`std::set` is sorted by default).

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be this:

```
template<typename Set>

bool set_compare(Set const &lhs, Set const &rhs){
    return lhs.size() == rhs.size() 
        && equal(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin());
}
```

Inspired from the elegant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473009/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-maps-of-strings-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

**C++11 standard on `==` for `std::set`**

Others [have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648810/895245) that `operator==` does compare `std::set` contents and works, but here is a quote from the [C++11 N3337 standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/raw/master/papers/n3337.pdf) which I believe implies that.

The quote is exactly the same as that for `std::vector` which I have interpreted in full detail at: [C++: Comparing two vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248044/c-comparing-two-vectors/58729931#58729931)

As a short summary to avoid duplication with that other answer:

- 23.2.1 "General container requirements" states that all containers use `equal()` for `operator==`
- 25.2.11 "Equal" defines `equal` and explicitly shows that it iterates over both containers comparing the elements of each

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 and above you could use `==` to compare whether the 2 sets are equal or not.

```
std::set<int> contOne{ 10,20,30,40,50 };
std::set<int> contTwo{ 50,40,30,20,10 };
std::cout << (contOne == contTwo) ? 1 : 0; // 1
```

Also, you could use `==` to compare the 2 **unordered sets** as well.

```
std::unordered_set<int> contOne{ 10,20,30,40,50 };
std::unordered_set<int> contTwo{ 50,40,30,20,10 };
std::cout << (contOne == contTwo) ? 1 : 0; // 1
```

As long as the keys are the same and the size is the same the containers will compare equal **no matter what order the keys are in.**