# Compute hash of map structure

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unordered-map

I would like to compute a hash value of an `unordered_map` data structure as a whole. This enables to easily compare two `map`s whether they contain exactly the same key-value-pairs or not.

Obviously, one can iterate over the included pairs, build a long string an hash it afterwards but I can imagine that there are better ways to do this.

For the moment, the actual hash function is not that crucial. I think `md5` would be ok. `sha` too of course.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to combine hash values for all the keys and all the values together. Ideally, in such a way that allows you to update map's hash while map entries are added/removed/updated. Note that equality of hashes doesn't guarantee equality of maps' contents, but it still allows you to quickly find out whether these contents differ.

Comment: Yes, you're right of course. I did not mention hash collisions.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need a commutative combine function, which `boost::hash_combine` *deliberatly isn't*, so that equal `unordered_map`, that have a differing internal order, have equal hashes. For that, I suggest just xoring the hash of each element.

```
template<typename UnorderedMap>
std::size_t hash(const UnorderedMap & um)
{
    boost::hash<typename UnorderedMap::value_type> elem_hash;
    auto combine = [&](size_t acc, typename UnorderedMap::const_reference elem){ return acc ^ elem_hash(elem); };
    return std::accumulate(um.begin(), um.end(), 0, combine);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am not so familiar with templates and lambdas. First of all, the argument of the combine function probably should be named elem? How do I call this function afterwards? Where to locate the template? In the header or source file? And: Does it take both `map->first` and `map->second` into account?

Comment: @lukasl1991 Oops. `combine` is called by accumulate, which is in `<numeric>`. I checked, and `std::hash` isn't specialised for pairs, but `boost::hash` is.

Comment: You cannot use modern C++ edficiently without being familiar with templates and lambdas.

Comment: @Caleth This seems to be what I need. Thank you very much! A final question: My unordered map is wrapped in a class `A` which is splitted in an `A.cpp` and an `A.hpp` file. Where to store the template definition? What is best practice? Even outside both files?

Comment: The template needs to be visible in every translation unit that wants to hash UnorderedMaps, so in it's own header is a common solution. It could go in `A.cpp` right now, but later you may want to reference it elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use boost's `hash_combine()` for combining hash of each entries. If you don't want to use boost, you can use xoring of the individual hash values to finally result in a combined hash value.

Additionally you can go through the below answer which describes how you can compare 2 maps without using hash combine:

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8473603/10142547)

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably xor the individual values. Moreover I will take a look at the referenced answer :-)

Comment: This is only appropriate for `map`, not `unordered_map`

Comment: Good advice :-D