# Finding and erasing a value from a std::vector holding std::map elements

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap

First, I have the following two objects, both filled with data:

```
std::vector<std::map<std::uint8_t, std::uint8_t>> x1;
std::vector<std::map<std::uint8_t, std::uint8_t>> x2;
```

My objective is to search inside `x2` (by the *key*), checking if any value from `x1` doesn't exist inside `x2`, and then erase it from `x1`.

I tried with the following code snippet, but to no avail (it doesn't compile!):

```
for (auto i = x1.begin(); i != x1.end(); ++i)
{
    auto it = std::find(x2.begin(), x2.end(), i);
    
    if (it == x2.end())
    {
        x1.erase(i);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Could you please share some insights on how to solve this problem?

Comment: `x1.erase(i);` invalidate `i` that you increment afterward.

Comment: To pass compilation: `auto it = std::find(x2.begin(), x2.end(), *i);` (missing star).

Comment: Can you sort vector? `std::set_union` might help then.

Comment: Good point on the invalidation of `i` after erase. I tried with `std::set_intersection`, but getting wrong results! Yes, I don't have an issue sorting vector.

Comment: @Xigma -- The vectors should be sorted before calling `std::set_intersection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also go a little bit functional: [Playground](https://repl.it/repls/DryLovingQuotient#main.cpp)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

// removes maps from x1, that are equal to none of x2 maps 
auto remove_start = std::remove_if(x1.begin(), x1.end(), [&](const auto& x1_map){ 
  return std::none_of(x2.begin(), x2.end(), 
    std::bind(std::equal_to(), x1_map, std::placeholders::_1)); 
});
x1.erase(remove_start, x1.end());
```

**EDIT: To check keys only, change std::equal_to to a custom lambda**

```
auto keys_equal = [](auto& m1, auto& m2){ 
  return m1.size() == m2.size() 
    && std::equal(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin(), 
      [](auto& kv1, auto& kv2){ return kv1.first == kv2.first; });
};

// removes maps from x1, that are equal to none of x2 maps 
auto remove_start = 
  std::remove_if(x1.begin(), x1.end(), [&](const auto& x1_map){ 
    return std::none_of(x2.begin(), x2.end(), 
      std::bind(keys_equal, x1_map, std::placeholders::_1)); 
  });
x1.erase(remove_start, x1.end());
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Thank you! For whatever reason, it is not working for me!

Comment: @Xigma might be that you don't use C++17 compilation

Comment: I am using C++17 compilation. It is just that it it erasing everything from x1!

Comment: @Xigma Strange, because it works in the playground I linked

Comment: Indeed, the example you gave works fine! If it matters, this is how I'm pushing my data into the vector:

`x1.push_back({ std::make_pair('a', 'b') });`

Comment: @Xigma it shouldn't matter if your type is still `std::vector<std::map<std::uint8_t, std::uint8_t>>`. Pretty sure `x1.push_back({ { 'a', 'b' } });` would work in C++17 too

Comment: Right, that notation works too. It is quite bizarre that it is deleting the entire vector!

Comment: @Xigma maybe you misspelled something or overrided `==` comparison of maps

Comment: I'm not doing any of that! I have a question though, this `x1.erase(remove_start, x1.end());` technically would end up erasing the whole of x1.

Comment: @Xigma it erases from `remove_start` to `x1.end()`, `remove_start` is initialized by `remove_if`, which would move all the soon-to-be-deleted maps in a tail of the vector

Comment: @Xigma so `remove_start` should point to the first map to be deleted after `remove_if` moved all the unmatched maps

Comment: I see! That makes sense.

Comment: @ Alex Larionov I think the problem here is that the comparison isn't specific to the _key_, and thus why it is ending up removing all the elements of `x1` in my case. I'm only interested in checking the _key_.

Comment: @Xigma well you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8473603/8564999) question to compare keys only. Check my edit for updated version

Comment: that's great! This is what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your code:

- `std::find()` searches for a single matching element, which in this case means you have to give it a `std::map` to search for.  But you are passing in the `i` iterator itself, not the `std::map` that it refers to.  You need to dereference `i`, eg:

  `auto it = std::find(x2.cbegin(), x2.cend(), *i);`
- When calling `x1.erase(i)`, `i` becomes invalidated, which means the loop cannot use `i` anymore - not for `++i`, not for `i != x1.end()`.  You need to save the new iterator that `erase()` returns, which refers to the *next* element after the one being erased.  Which means you also need to update your loop logic to NOT increment `i` when `erase()` is called, eg:

  ```cpp
  for (auto i = x1.cbegin(); i != x1.cend(); )
  {
      auto it = std::find(x2.cbegin(), x2.cend(), *i);

      if (it == x2.cend())
          i = x1.erase(i);
      else
          ++i;
  }
  ```
- lastly, when using `std::find()`, you are comparing entire `std::map` objects to each other.  If you are interested in comparing only the *keys*, try something more like this:

  ```cpp
  for (auto i = x1.cbegin(); i != x1.cend(); )
  {
      const auto &m1 = *i:

      auto it = std::find_if(m1.cbegin(), m1.cend(),
          [&](const decltype(m1)::value_type &m1_pair) { // or (const auto &m1_pair) in C++14...
              return std::find_if(x2.cbegin(), x2.cend(),
                  [&](const decltype(x2)::value_type &m2){ // or (const auto &m2) in C++14...
                      return m2.find(m1_pair.first) != m2.cend();
                  }
              );
          }
      );

      if (it == m1.cend())
          i = x1.erase(i);
      else
          ++i;
  }
  ```

Comment: @Jarod42 true, which is why I said *IF*.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks a lot for the detailed and informative response. Indeed, I'm only interested in comparing the _keys_.

Comment: @RemyLebeau With the _keys_ comparison based approach, the compiler is throwing an error: "find': is not a member of 'std::vector<std::map<uint8"...

Comment: @Xigma sorry, forgot to take the `vector`s into account.  I updated my example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! Unfortunately, the compiler is still throwing errors on the updated version "error C2451: conditional expression of type '_InIt' is illegal". I'm using MS VC 2017.